# how to check and delete if file uploaded before with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i build function to upload zip files but when user upload file two times it didnt delete the first uploaded file but added increment number to the file name (( file.zip,file1.zip,file2.zip,,,etc )

so i want to tell the function when the user uploaded the same file name delete the first file and upload this second file or replace it ... anyone help me how to do that...

```
/**
 * change book source file
 * 
 * @param integer $book_id 
 */
public function upload_book_zip($book_id) {
    $vars = array();
    $vars['upload_path'] = PUBPATH . 'global/modules/bookstore/files/books_source_file/';
    $vars['allowed_types'] = 'zip';
    $vars['max_size'] = '30720';
    $vars['book_id'] = $book_id;

    $book = $this->d_book->find_by_id($book_id);
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $file_name = $this->upload($vars);
        if ($file_name === NULL) { // error happens while uploading file
            $vars['upload_errors'] = $this->upload->display_errors("<p class='notification n-error'>", "</p>");
        } else {
            $this->d_book->update_one_field($book_id, 'bo_path_zip', $file_name);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', lang('file_uploaded'));
            redirect('bookstore/admin_d_book/');
        }
    } else {
        $vars['upload_errors'] = NULL;
    }

    if ($book->bo_path_zip) { // load cover image
        $vars['file_path'] = base_url() . 'global/modules/bookstore/files/books_source_file/' . $book->bo_path_zip;
    } else {
        $vars['file_path'] = NULL;
    }
    $vars['controller_name'] = 'admin_d_book';
    $this->view('bookstore/admin/change_zip_file', $vars);
}

    /**
 * 
 * @param array $config the configuration array
 * @return string
 * 
 */
private function upload($config) {
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
        return $uploadData['file_name'] = NULL;
    } else {
        $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
        log_message('debug', 'file has been uploaded ok - file name is ' . $uploadData['file_name']);
        return $uploadData['file_name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: you can look this page http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by adding

```
$vars['overwrite'] = TRUE;
```

better check File upload [library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Answer (score 1):

Set `overwrite` to true in the config array you pass

```
    $vars = array();
    $vars['upload_path'] = 'filepath here';
    $vars['allowed_types'] = 'zip';
    $vars['max_size'] = '30720';
    $vars['book_id'] = $book_id;

    // add this line
    $vars['overwrite'] = true;

    // the old file will now get overwritten
    $file_name = $this->upload($vars)
```

Answer (score 0):

A better method is to check the md5 or sha1 checksum of the file.

If two users uploads two different files with the same name to the server, the file on server will be overwritten and it is impossible to distingush the file by just name.

Also, it can be done easily in PHP.